# Number of Operation Contract in WCF

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

It might be a silly question, but I am wondering what other professionals deal with number of list for Operation contract. I am developing WCF web service, so I have only four exposed Operation Contracts. Let's say I have like 500 Operation Contracts in the IWcfService. Should I just list all 500 contracts in the list like below or is there anyway that I can categorize to make things easier to maintain?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String CheckService();

    [OperationContract]
    String GetMessage();

    [OperationContract]
    svcEmployeeDetail GetEmployeeDetail(string userID, string userPW,string employeeID);

    [OperationContract]
    List<svcEmployeeWorkHistory> GetEmployeeWorkHistory(string userID, string userPW, string employeeID);
   }
```

Comment: A well designed service should have 7 to 9 service calls - definitely not significantly more than that. 500 service methods is way beyond good and evil - that's a service I wouldn't want to maintain into the future, or even call!

Comment: @marc_s. That is good point, but I am still wondering how it is possibly have only 7 to 9 service call for large application? For example, let's say   I am developing HR system. I will just list what I need. I need to provide few dropdownlists as a search condition such as "Company", "Department", "Section, and "Pay Type" and so one. I guess I will need at least 150 operation contrasts. Should I separate them as multiple servicse? Like services for dropdownlist, select, update, insert, and delete. Let me know what the best solution is.

Comment: You should group your service by topic - e.g. have one service for `Customer` - you'll get a `GetCustomer`, maybe `NewCustomer` and so on - but typically not more than a handful service methods. Maybe you can combine your several service calls for those dropdown lists into a single call `GetSearchCriteria` or something like that - one that would return a set of values. Smaller, more focused services are also a lot easier to maintain and update!

Comment: @marc_s. I got your point. I just need to pass a value like "Company" or "Section" as parameter. Then I can use one service call for all the dropdownlist query since they all return ValueField and TextField as same way.

Comment: There is similar question for this. It seems like huge subject.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233571/best-practice-for-large-wcf-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had 500 methods on your service I would suggest you'd need to create some new services based on methods that operate on similar things.

500 methods on one service would be confusing for consumers and a large maintenance headache, let alone violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)